# Ralink PCI Wifi adaptor intermittently drops connection

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04, ralink

This card had been working flawlessly for several years on Ubuntu 12.04, 14.04, and recently 16.04 but after a recent update it started dropping connection for no apparent reason. Distance from router is about 20 feet through a couple of walls and nothing environmentally has changed. I ran the wireless script from @chili555 answer [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

this is the resulting [pastebin report.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23315155/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this problem by turning off power management on my card by editing the wifi power management configuration with  the command `sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`

The file contained 2 lines:

```
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3
```

I thought this was surprising as I knew I had disabled power management back in the 12.04 days until I realized I had done a fresh install of 16.04 rather than an upgrade on this particular system when I went from 14.04 to 16.04

I changed it to:

```
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 0
```

After a reboot I had no further problems. Wifi stayed connected reliably.

Comment: Only issue with this solution is that every Network Manager update will prompt if you want to keep your settings in this file.  I think we would be better off if a bug report is filed complaining about this change

Comment: @Jeremy31  I don't mind saying no to the prompt (as long as I get it).  Why do you consider this to be a bug? My memory of  disabling power management back in 12.04 may be faulty but if I'm right it wasn't a change, but something that has been this way AFAIK. Can you verify that it changed? I assume this is something they did to save power on laptops (which doesn't concern me on this desktop) but it may have value as configured for those in a more portable condition. ;-)

Comment: The change was to only enable power management when on battery power see [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1557026) and this doesn't appear to be true

Comment: @Jeremy31 Thank you. It appears that bug has been effectively squashed.

Comment: After seeing some source code it might be better to have `wifi.powersave = 2` as that is what I needed to do on one laptop as that really disables powersave from being enabled

Comment: @Jeremy31 All solutions are situation dependent IMHO. :-)