# Wifi disconnected after resume 16.04 - Other solutions don't work

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04, network-manager, suspend

I am a new Ubuntu user and have so far really enjoyed it. However, I spent around 3 hours yesterday trying to get my wifi to resume after my laptop wakes from sleep mode (it works if i reboot). I have scoured message boards and all the links on google are purple 3 or 4 pages in for every search result on this matter. Therefore, I don't think this question will be a repeat.

I have

- A Dell Inspiron 15
- AMD A6-6310
- Ubuntu A6-6310
- My wireless card is labeled as (device) wlp3s0 (driver) ath9k

and I have tried the following:

I have put these into a config folder in /config.d

```
SUSPEND_MODULES="$SUSPEND_MODULES ath9k"

SUSPEND_MODULES="ath9k"
```

I have created executable files in /sleep.d such as:

```
 #!/bin/sh
#Tell Network Manager that resume was successful
case "$1" in
        thaw)
       /usr/bin/nmcli nm sleep false
      ;;
 esac

#!/bin/sh

case "${1}" in
 resume|thaw)
 nmcli r wifi off && nmcli r wifi on ;;
esac
```

and many other variants thereof.

Also, this restarts the NetworkManager but does not connect wifi again:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

There are a couple other things I have tried that I can't exactly remember with commands like nmcli d wifi on, or something. They didnt work.

**Now, I may be wrong, but I think the problem *might* lie in this:**

```
sudo nmcli nm sleep false
```

Now, my terminal does NOT recognize "nm" and says:

```
sudo nmcli nm sleep false
```

and when I pull up the menu for nmcli, nm is nowhere in the object list. I feel like this might be the key to the problem. So, is there anything that I haven't done that I should do and is there any way to "fix" the "nm" problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe not the same problem (I'm with _intel driver_) but I'm facing similar if not the same issues and ended assigning a shortcut (`FN+F9` in my case) to execute the command `pkexec systemctl restart network-manager.service` to tell systemd to restart network-manager from the GUI in the least intrusive way i found.

Comment: for what's worth: version of my `nmcli` is **1.2.2**

Comment: Please see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) and edit the post to include the information

Comment: @TimothyTruckle you may just ask your own question as Ryan Callihan hasn't been logged in since Nov 7

Comment: @Jeremy31 *"Please see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)"* His is not the same question since we (the TO an me) have the probem only after the system resumes from suspend.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle it might be an issue with dnsmasq, try `sudo sed -i 's/dns=dnsmasq/#dns=dnsmasq/' /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`  Then reboot

Comment: @TimothyTruckle The version of nmcli included with 16.04 no longer supports the `nm` object, nor the `sleep` command. Personally I would [turn off power management](http://askubuntu.com/questions/836271/ralink-pci-wifi-adaptor-intermittently-drops-connection) on the wireless interface to avoid the initial disconnection or  perhaps attempt bring down all Network manager interfaces on suspend and bring them all up on resume.

Comment: @ElderGeek unfortunately this did not solve the problem either, the WiFi is still disconnected after suspend... :o(

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I apologize for my confusion, but could you clarify as to what did not solve the problem? Are you refering to turning off power management or bringing down the interfaces on suspend and back up on resume? Perhaps your approach and the results of your testing could provide me some clues that would allow us to further assist you. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @ElderGeek I followed the steps in the answer you linked to http://askubuntu.com/questions/836271/ralink-pci-wifi-adaptor-intermittently-drops-connection and that did not solve the problem on my laptop. If you're suggesting somthing ese please add an answer with detailed explanation.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I'll see what I can come up with. Can you provide us with the output of `uname -a`

Comment: @ElderGeek  *"Can you provide us with the output of uname -a"* :   Linux tt-LIFEBOOK-E8420 4.4.0-57-generic #78-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 9 23:50:32 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50912/discussion-between-elder-geek-and-timothy-truckle).

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Driver misbehavior on returning from suspend is a problem I've run across several times with several network interfaces across several operating systems. The only thing I've found to be effective across all of these is to turn power management off for the WiFi card. After reviewing the adjustments I made to a system to resolve a similar problem I offer the following resolution.

First we will make a backup of existing default power management settings with:

```
sudo cp /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf.bak
```

Next we will edit the content to turn power management for WiFi off entirely. with gksu gedit /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf which contains the default value `wifi.powersave = 3` which enables power saving on the WiFi device. Changing the content of this file to:

```
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 0
```

Completing the above and also [renaming my interface to wlan0](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767786/changing-network-interfaces-name-ubuntu-16-04)
resolved my issues under 16.04

Once that is done you'll need to reboot or issue the command `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager` to restart Network Manager

Note: My card does not have an Atheros chip and is identified as follows:

*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT2561/RT61 802.11g PCI
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:04:01.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: 00:1a:ef:03:00:aa
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless

Alternatives that may work for others with a similar problem are:

Put the bash script below in your `/etc/pm/sleep.d` folder
with a name like 99_wifiup.

**NOTE:** The 99_ is needed where the 99 is the highest number in the folder to ensure it runs last.

You'll need to insure that the script has execute permissions and you'll need superuser (sudo) permissions to write the file there.
Once in place every time you come out of suspend it will run.

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in
suspend | hibernate)
# executed on suspend
;;
resume | thaw)
# executed on resume
/usr/sbin/rfkill block all
/usr/sbin/rfkill unblock all
/sbin/iwlist wlan0 scan
;;
*)
;;
esac
```

If that doesn't work it should be worth exploring modifying the script to issue the commands `nmcli networking off` on suspend and `nmcli networking on` on thaw.

If none of these solutions work for you and you notice other anomalies you may have a faulty WiFi adapter or perhaps [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/432353) has been resurrected.

Sources:

Modified /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf and /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules on one of my systems.

Mickeypop post #9 https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2321399

`man nmcli`

https://gist.github.com/jcberthon/ea8cfe278998968ba7c5a95344bc8b55

Comment: should I put `nmcli networking on` as first or as last command in the *resume* branch?

Comment: I have to try again with the real WiFi if name...

Comment: Apologies. I should have asked for that...

Comment: No excuses please, should have realized that myself earlier... Anyway, WiFi still does not come back... when I issue the command manually (sudo ..) after resume the last one answeres: `wlp32s0   Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down`

Comment: beside this I found this in the syslog: `ath5k: phy0: can't reset hardware (-5)`

Comment: Gotta love Atheros....  can you give me the output of `sudo lshw -C network` via a [pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) link? and also `rfkill list` Thank you.

Comment: before resum: http://pastebin.com/VRu4LhLG  http://pastebin.com/1R8S7Ns5

Comment: after resume (combined) http://pastebin.com/Mnpj9B6r

Comment: That's odd. It's losing the Model and Manufacturer! Let's reboot and try `nmcli networking on` as the only command in the resume | thaw branch

Comment: this is the output after resume: http://pastebin.com/ZgZY5Y7N

Comment: maybe we should return to the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50912/discussion-between-elder-geek-and-timothy-truckle)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50920/discussion-between-elder-geek-and-timothy-truckle).

Comment: `wifi.powersave` should be set to 2, not 0... https://gist.github.com/jcberthon/ea8cfe278998968ba7c5a95344bc8b55#file-networkmanager-wifi-powersave-md

Comment: @Fadi Are you aware that this answer was written in 2016 and you are linking to data that appears to be from 2020? This is what worked for me and apparently others at the time. Please feel free to write your own answer. You might include the version of Ubuntu that you tested on. Change is the only constant. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I've found wifi power management often to be a bane of the linux experience. In my case, it was across various Intel and Broadcom adapters. Perhaps disabling it will resolve your issue.  Here is how I do it (edit for your interface `wlp3s0`):

Create: `/etc/network/if-up.d/wifi-powerman-off`
Enable: `chmod +x /etc/network/if-up.d/wifi-powerman-off`

`wifi-powerman-off:`

```
#!/bin/sh
IWCONFIG=/sbin/iwconfig
WLAN_IFACE=<<interface name>>
if [ ! -x $IWCONFIG ]; then
    exit 1
fi
if [ "$IFACE" = $WLAN_IFACE ]; then
    $IWCONFIG $IFACE power off
fi
```

Here is the original Q & A reference:
[How can I prevent iwconfig power management from being turned on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85214/how-can-i-prevent-iwconfig-power-management-from-being-turned-on)

Comment: I created that file and rebooted, but still the WiFi is disconnected after suspend...

Comment: shame ... was hopeful for you. At least you know it isn't the power mgmt component.

Answer (score -1):

few commands to try (in addition to the above), if you find one of them to work (when running manually) - add it to one of the scripts you mentioned in the question to be run during wakeup.

restart network & wifi related services:

```
sudo service wpa_supplicant restart

sudo service network-manager restart
```

restart the network card:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down && sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

force wifi card mode:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid any
```

(on older ubuntu versions the state is called `auto`, not `any`)

reload the network card kernel drivers (the list might need to be updated for your drivers, the list was taken from a script I use on another model):

```
sudo rmmod ath9k ath9k_common ath9k_hw ath mac80211 rndis_wlan cfg80211 rndis_host cdc_ether usbnet && sleep 1 && sudo modprobe -a usbnet cdc_ether rndis_host cfg80211 rndis_wlan mac80211 ath ath9k_hw ath9k_common ath9k
```

Comment: my version of `iwconfig` (Wireless-Tools version 30
          Compatible with Wireless Extension v11 to v22.) does not know of command *auto*

Comment: how do I get the (complete but minimal) list of modules to use with `rmmod`/`modprobe`?

Comment: when you try to `rmmod` a module, you get a list of modules depends on it, following those lists is how I got this list.

Comment: it turns out the `auto` was renamed to `any` in newer ubuntu versions.