# Wifi cannot reconnect in any way after long time sleep/suspend/hibernate

Tags: 16.04, wireless, network-manager, suspend

I just installed ubuntu 16.04. I have the problem that wifi cannot reconnect in any way after a long time sleep or suspend or hibernate( I leave the computer until next day ).

I googled, I've tried any method I can find online, but they don't work:

1. I followed this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/905019/419887), edit the /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf, but it's not working
2. this [thread](http://www.debugpoint.com/2016/05/quick-fix-no-wireless-connection-after-sleep-suspend-in-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus/), run the command: `systemctl restart network-manager.service`
3. sudo killall NetworkManager && sudo NetworkManager
4. $ sudo nmcli networking off
   $ sudo nmcli networking on
5. $ sudo ifdown -a
   $ sudo ifup -a
6. sudo ifconfig wlp4s0 up
   service network-manager restart

I don't know whether my problem is caused by this bug, but I don't see the fix for this bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1574347

`nmcli dev` shows that the type is wifi, but it is disconnect, I can't make it reconnect except reboot system.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I have the same problem.  After a lot of research the prevailing wisdom was that it is a bug.  I've been through a few upgrades since, but still running 16.04.  Haven;t tried it recently.  If I need to be away from the computer for a while I just use the lock account feature.  Recovery from suspend is painful if not impossible.  After having to reboot a few times I just quit using it.

Comment: There's some good information at https://askubuntu.com/questions/845800/wifi-disconnected-after-resume-16-04-other-solutions-dont-work?rq=1 No clear solutions but the advice involves fooling with power management.

Comment: This might help out: https://askubuntu.com/questions/898297/wifi-signal-icon-switches-to-ethernet-icon-up-down-arrows-after-suspend/899304#899304

Answer (score -1):

I recently had this problem with Elementary OS. I tried everything under the Google sun, but the only thing that solved my problem was to do a very hard turning off and on by **reinstalling the OS**.

I understand that this is not thy type of answer you were looking for, but it is a potentially valid solution, if all else fails. I believe that there is a prolific variety of Q&A on this very problem through the Internet. I encourage you to look through these and to report the results here.

Comment: This answer does not address the question being asked.  In addition, reinstalling the OS will definitely NOT solve this problem.

Comment: It did in my case